# MEDIA_BUTTON broadcast receiver doesn't receive headset button actions

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I use a `MediaButtonEventReceiver` Broadcast receiver for detecting headset button actions.

```
    ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE))
            .registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(
                    getPackageName(), MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class
                            .getName()));
```

It's works fine in most phones, But in galaxy s4 when it's own music player plays my app gets ignored and it can't receive media button actions, and music player takes the control of headset button. I tried setting a high priority to my broadcast receiver in manifest file.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100000000000000" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But it didn't worked. How can I solve this problem?